# What does 'while' with an integer mean in Python and how does this GCD code work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found this greatest common denominator code:

```
def gcd(x,y):
    while y:
        x, y = y, x % y
    return x
```

I cannot understand what we mean by `while y` as `y` is an integer. How does it work? Furthermore, what does the line `x, y = y, x % y` add to the code?

Comment: an elegant little algorithm!  here `y` is being used like `bool(y)`, which will return `True` if and only if `y != 0`.  the middle line is a bit of syntactic sugar in python, tuple unpacking.

Comment: @wim: Please post answers like this as answers so we can vote them up properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `while`, read this: http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement

It says "This repeatedly tests the expression and, if it is true, executes the first suite;"

Now the question is: What's True?

Read this: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bool

Then read this: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Non-zero values are True.  Zero is false.

> What does the line "x, y=y, x%y" add to the code?

Makes precious little sense as a question.  "add to the code"?  What?  What part is confusing?

Read this: http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

"If the target list is a comma-separated list of targets: The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list, and the items are assigned, from left to right, to the corresponding targets."

For the integer '%' operator, read this: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

It would help if your question was more specific.  It's hard to answer as asked.

Answer (score 4):

1. The loop ceases when `y==0`.
2. The loop body simultaneously assigns `y` to `x` and `x%y` to `y`. Otherwise, you would need a temporary variable to execute both assignments, because one of them would be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `while y` will iterate so long as `y` is not zero.

The other line is performing the two operations atomically:

```
new_x <-- old_x
new_y <-- old_x mod old_y
```

This performs euclidean algorithm for GCD, and the tuple assignment obviates the need for a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

Greatest Common Divisor using the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

```
while y != 0:
    temp = y
    y = x % y
    x = temp
return x
```